# Insert SPWebConfigModification at beginning of httpModules node

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

We've built a simple IHttpModule for our SharePoint deployment that catches exceptions and emails the developers the contents using the following foundation:

```
public class ExceptionReporter : IHttpModule
{
    //snip

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler(context_Error);
    }

    void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    //snip
}
```

In trying to deploy it the "proper" way, we're using a **SPWebConfigModification** to add the type to the <**httpModules**> node of web.config.

Our problem is that the first <add /> in <**htpModules**> is **Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule**, which catches and clears all exceptions, preventing our handler from working with the error.  We've verified this behavior both by manually modifying the web.config to put our handler before **SPRequestModule** and using Reflector to view the actions of the **SPRequestModule**.

What is the "best practice" way to get this entry into web.config and appear before **SPRequestModule**?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Tried to hook the Application_Error event int he Global.asax, You should be able to do  what you are trying to do in Module.

Comment: No, we haven't tried that yet since I've seen references to that not being a best practice.  How would you suggest changing that file as part of a WSP deploy, since it's underneath inetpub instead of in the 12 hive?  Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122205/how-can-you-hook-a-sharepoint-2007-feature-into-the-applicationstart-of-a-site